# html::link to dynamic route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to output a list of users on my blade.php page. Clicking on a user's id should take you to an individual profile page.

Here is my **View** **browse.blade.php file**

```
<?php
$cars = DB::table('cars')->get();
foreach ($cars as $car)
{
     echo "<table >" ;
     echo "<tr>";
     HTML::linkRoute('browse/'.$car->car_id, 'Car ID: '.$car->car_id);
     echo "<td>Make: $car->make <br/ ></td>" ;
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

My **Controller**

```
public function browse()
{
    return View::make('car/browse');
}

public function showProfile($car_id)
{
    return View::make('car/profile')->with('car_id', $car_id);
}
```

My **Route**

```
Route::any('browse/{car_id}', 'BrowseController@showProfile');
```

I want my view page to output a bunch of cars in my Database. Clicking on a car with car_id = i should tak me to `http://localhost:8000/browse/i` for each respectic car_id.

Am I taking the wrong approach with my html::linkRoute?

Typing `http://localhost:8000/browse/i` into the browser works for any i. Therefore, my route and showProfile is working properly.

However when I load the **browse.blade.php** I receive the following error
[image]

10018 is my first car id. Why isn't my `Route::any('browse/{car_id}`' working?

---

**edit:**

Thanks to msturdy for the suggestion

changed
    Route::any('browse/{car_id}', 'BrowseController@showProfile');

to

```
Route::any('browse/{car_id}', [
    'as' => 'profile',
    'uses' => 'BrowseController@showProfile']);
```

and changed HTML route to

```
HTML::linkRoute('profile', 'Car ID: '.$car->car_id, array($car->car_id));
```

The errors are gone but no link is displaying on the browse page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, update your route so that it has a ['name' you can use elsewhere in your application](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes).  We'll call it 'browse' in this example:

```
Route::any('browse/{car_id}', array('as' => 'browse', 'uses' => 'BrowseController@showProfile'));
```

Then `HTML::linkRoute()` takes this route name, the title of the link and the parameters as separate arguments:

```
 HTML::linkRoute('browse', "Car ID: " . $car->car_id, array($car->car_id));
```

Comment: That eliminated all the errors but for some reason browse.blade.php is not displaying 'Car ID: '.$car->car_id  at all. It seems to be skipping it. Do I need to put it in a hyperlink?

Comment: Still no luck. I feel like we are very close.

Comment: Just had to add an echo. My fault for not realizing the easy mistake. Thank you so much for your help. Out of curiosity, should I always assign 'names' to routes? If so, why?

Comment: ah! that'd do it, I didn't understand what wasn't showing.. :)  Named routes are useful as you can update the location of it in the future without having to update it in all the views.  It can be more convenient as well.. depends on you and your application really!